# Py2app can't find module

Tags: python, macos, py2app

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['EDWTON.py']
DATA_FILES = ['edwton_logotipo.icns']

OPTIONS = {
 'iconfile':'edwton_logotipo.icns',
 'argv_emulation': True,
 'packages': [" discord", " requests"],
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    #options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I want to make an app with python on macOS, but it can't find the imported modules. Does anyone know how to fix this?